# Firebase storage getDownloadURL keeps returning error of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-storage

I am trying to show an image in my Vue/Quasar project which is stored in Firebase storage. I followed every step in the docs. every time I use the getDownloadURL() method I get this error "Cannot read property 'getdownloadURL' of undefined". Anyone knows why my code is not working?

I have also tried every other method in the Firebase docs and I get the same error.

> storage.refFromURL('gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg')

Firebase.js File

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();
const ref = storage.ref("03.png");

export { db, storage, Ref };
```

My vue component file

```
import ref from "@/firebase.js";
import storage from "@/firebase.js";
import db from "@/firebase.js";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    CreateCharacter,
  },
  date() {
    return {
      img: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log(Ref);
    console.log(storage);
    console.log(db);
  },
  methods: {
    handle() {
      Ref.getdownloadURL().then((url) => {
        console.log(url);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casing is critial. Uppercase and lowercase are considered to be different. `ref` and `getDownloadURL`.

Also, your `import` could use some work.

I believe it should be something like:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();
const ref = storage.ref("03.png");

export { db, storage, ref }; // *** changed, needs to match casing of `const`
```

And:

```js
import { db, storage, ref } from "@/firebase.js"; // *** changed, destructure object 
                                                  // *** rather than using multiple imports

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    CreateCharacter,
  },
  date() {
    return {
      img: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log(ref); // *** changed, fix casing
    console.log(storage);
    console.log(db);
  },
  methods: {
    handle() {
      ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => { // *** changed, fix casing
        console.log(url);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was all in the imports. which I still don't understand why the way I did the imports didn't work. (Other than the casing of course)

Comment: `export` exports a single thing. In this case, it's an object like `{"db": db, "storage": storage, "ref": ref}` through the magic of [object property shorthand](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/). `import` imports the single thing that was exported. You could do something like `import { db } from "@/firebase.js";` to get close to your original syntax. It's still [object destructuring](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-object-array-destructuring-es2015#object-destructuring) though so it's more convenient to combine them.